# Click tracking with JS

Tags: javascript, redirect, tracking

We are working on system which is tracking Clicks with JavaScript. The problem is, there are some user which have disabled the javascript but we need to count this Clicks as well. When we make a  tag, then all the bots will come to this section as well.
Do you have some suggestions how we can handle this in the best way?

The actual tracking, before we redirect to the real URL is:

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="1;url=__URL__">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
        document.write("<img src=\'script.php?parameter' width=\"1\" height=\"1\" \'> ");
    // -->
    </script>
```

We redirect to given URL and in the same time we are displaying an 1x1 Pixel what is doing the tracking on our system.
Do you thing there is better and secure way to track the click and to redirect to the given url, so we don't lost clicks? At this moment we have some clicks lost, but we don't know in which situation.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you also want users who have disabled JavaScript, why are you using JavaScript to place the image? Why not just straight into the HTML?

Comment: how about all links leading to one page, which handles the 'click' and then redirects, kinda like how facebook and a majority of other sites do it ?

Comment: I have used JS to prevent count of the clicks from Bots. Any other Idea how to handle this?

Comment: @php_nub_qq yes I am handling it in the same way. I have an click.php, what is doing the redirect and the click traking. But there are some clicks missing and I don't know why.

Comment: How do you know they're missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `noscript` tag for that:

```
<script>
   doWhateverYouWantToDo();
</script>

<noscript>
  <img src="script.php?parameter" width="1" height="1">
</noscript>
```

Comment: But in this way all the bots which are not handeling JS will be counted as well. This is what I don't want. Is there other solution?

Comment: Why not just using a `robots.txt`?

Comment: Hmm I am using, but they don't care about :D